# Angular CDK Overlay Module: CanDeactivateGuard should launch custom modal

Tags: angular

UPDATE:

I've refactored based on @Blind Despair's answer below. It now uses the Overlay Module from Angular CDK. Here's the code for the Guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PendingChangesGuard
  implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  content = 'A simple string content modal overlay';
  constructor(private overlayService: OverlayService) {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: ComponentCanDeactivate
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate()
      ? true
      : this.openConfirmDialog(this.content);
  }

  openConfirmDialog(content: TemplateRef<any> | ComponentType<any> | 
string) {
    const ref = this.overlayService.open(this.content, null);

    return ref.afterClosed$.subscribe((res) => {});
  }
}
```

The problem is this line is returning a subscription and my guard has to return either a boolean or Observable:

```
 return ref.afterClosed$.subscribe((res) => {});
```

Here is the *OverlayService* class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OverlayService {
  constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private injector: Injector) {}

  open<R = any, T = any>(
    content: string | TemplateRef<any> | Type<any>,
    data: T
  ): OverlayRef<R> {
    const configs = new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: true,
      panelClass: ['modal', 'is-active'],
      backdropClass: 'modal-background',
    });

    const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(configs);

    const myOverlayRef = new OverlayRef<R, T>(overlayRef, content, 
data);

    const injector = this.createInjector(myOverlayRef, this.injector);
    overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(OverlayComponent, null, 
injector));

    return myOverlayRef;
  }

  createInjector(ref: OverlayRef, inj: Injector) {
    const injectorTokens = new WeakMap([[RaOverlayRef, ref]]);
    return new PortalInjector(inj, injectorTokens);
  }
}
```

And here's the *Overlay* class:

```
export interface OverlayCloseEvent<R> {
  type: 'backdropClick' | 'close';
  data: R;
}

// R = Response Data Type, T = Data passed to Modal Type
export class OverlayRef<R = any, T = any> {
  afterClosed$ = new Subject<OverlayCloseEvent<R>>();

  constructor(
    public overlay: OverlayRef,
    public content: string | TemplateRef<any> | Type<any>,
    public data: T // pass data to modal i.e. FormData
  ) {
    overlay.backdropClick().subscribe(() => 
this._close('backdropClick', null));
  }

  close(data?: R) {
    this._close('close', data);
  }

  private _close(type: 'backdropClick' | 'close', data: R) {
    this.overlay.dispose();
    this.afterClosed$.next({
      type,
      data,
    });

    this.afterClosed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Any tips for how to refactor the *openConfirmDialog()* to return what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return a boolean in that guard, because opening modal is not enough to define the outcome it should give. You have to wait for user input, which means that your guard `canDeactivate` should either return a `Promise` or an `Observable`. Unfortunately your current modal dialog is too simple to support that use case. Basically you want to have something like `.afterClosed()` which returns `Promise<boolean>` or `Observable<boolean>` then when your user clicks yes/no you have to resolve a promise or emit a value into a subject and complete it. Then you can easily just return the result of `.afterClosed()` from your guard. But you would need to refactor your service and your modal for that. Of course you can have `afterClosed()` as a method on the modal component, but you don't want to expose all its methods to the guard or whatever would use it, so a good practice would be to introduce a `DialogRef` which would only expose what you want to be exposed. But why reinvent the wheel if this has been already solved? There is an amazing angular module called `@angular/cdk` which you can use to create a very smart modal dialog with low effort. You can check [this article](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/reusable-modal-overlay-using-angular-cdk-overlay/).

Comment: looks great, thanks for the tip. i specifically avoided using Material because of added bundle size plus I'm not using that many components. what am i looking at in terms of added weight to the bundle if i load this module?

Comment: in my project, parsed cdk is 42kb in main bundle, but when gzipped is only 10kb.

Comment: I've implemented the code in the tutorial but it's not playing nicely with the Guard, which expects a boolean or Observale<boolean>. The tutorial is returning a Subscription. I've updated my original post and wondering if you have time to take a look, please?

Comment: @fumeng you need to return just `.afterClosed$` without subscribing to it. That's going to be `Observable<boolean>`, if you set up everything correctly. I'll try to make stackblitz example for you with my own code.

Comment: I don't think I missed anything, I've copied the code almost completely.  But if I return ref.afterClosed$ then I get the error that the observable is a Subject<OverlayCloseEvent<any>> and not an Observable<boolean>. I've added that class in the post above.

Comment: then you need to return `.afterClosed$.pipe(pluck('data'))`. But of course your confirmation dialog needs to pass that data as boolean

Comment: I quickly create this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eyh1ym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprotected-deactivation.guard.ts
I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Can you just slighty refactor to something like...

```
canDeactivate(
    component: ComponentCanDeactivate
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    const _v = component.canDeactivate();
    if (!_v) {
      this.openConfirmDialog();
    }
    return _v;
  }
```